# Почему может оставаться горизонтальный скролл на адаптиве?

Tags: html, css

Есть страница: у body задано min-wight: 380px, у viewport content="width=device-width". Когда открываю сайт на мобильнике появляется небольшой горизонтальный скролл. На десктопе проверял блоков с фиксированной шириной и выходящих текстов нет. Блоки удалял, скрол все равно имеется. Может как то не отрабатывает зумирование на экранах меньше 380рх?

Comment: Эм, что-то я не понял вопроса, если device-width меньше чем 380px, то body не влезет по ширине и скролла в принципе не может не быть

Comment: Ну, так если у вас задан min-widht: 380px, на экранах меньше этого размера (360, 320) естественно будет скролл - а Вы как хотели?

Comment: слышал, что как то можно автоматом сделать, чтоб она вписывалась в размер устройства. то есть body зумировалось(уменьшалось) под размер экрана без скрола. или скрол будет всегда?